# Arduino: Read frequency of input from audio jack

Tags: arduino-uno, analogread, input

I want to trigger an arduino from a sound from an audio jack from a mobile phone. The audio is a 1 Khz sound that the mobile will play. I want to avoid accidental triggering of the audio by testing for specifically that frequency.

I've found several tutorials using analog read, but the output is not in hertz.

How do i get the output in Hertz?

```
int incomingAudio;

void setup(){
    Serial.begin(9600);  
}

void loop(){
  incomingAudio = analogRead(A0);//read voltage at A0
  incomingAudio = (incomingAudio+1)/4 - 1;//scale from 10 bit (0-1023) to 8 bit (0-255)
  if (incomingAudio<0){//deal with negative numbers
    incomingAudio = 0;
  }
  PORTD = incomingAudio;
  Serial.println(PORTD);

}
```

Comment: Edgar Bonets Program is ingeneous, but the power fluctuations tested with a tone at 1000 kHz (square wave Signal) are quite high. A factor of three using LOG_TAU = 6. May be, some improvement is possible.

Comment: @ChristianRempel: Testing with synthetic data shows the reported power fluctuates within a factor 2.2 with a square input and a factor 1.2 with a sinusoidal input.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can measure a single "pure" frequency by counting the number of times that the pin changes, by using the inbuilt timers. Here is a sketch from [my page about timers](http://www.gammon.com.au/timers) that accomplishes that:

```C++
// Timer and Counter example
// Author: Nick Gammon
// Date: 17th January 2012

// Input: Pin D5

// these are checked for in the main program
volatile unsigned long timerCounts;
volatile boolean counterReady;

// internal to counting routine
unsigned long overflowCount;
unsigned int timerTicks;
unsigned int timerPeriod;

void startCounting (unsigned int ms) 
  {
  counterReady = false;         // time not up yet
  timerPeriod = ms;             // how many 1 ms counts to do
  timerTicks = 0;               // reset interrupt counter
  overflowCount = 0;            // no overflows yet

  // reset Timer 1 and Timer 2
  TCCR1A = 0;             
  TCCR1B = 0;              
  TCCR2A = 0;
  TCCR2B = 0;

  // Timer 1 - counts events on pin D5
  TIMSK1 = bit (TOIE1);   // interrupt on Timer 1 overflow

  // Timer 2 - gives us our 1 ms counting interval
  // 16 MHz clock (62.5 ns per tick) - prescaled by 128
  //  counter increments every 8 µs. 
  // So we count 125 of them, giving exactly 1000 µs (1 ms)
  TCCR2A = bit (WGM21) ;   // CTC mode
  OCR2A  = 124;            // count up to 125  (zero relative!!!!)

  // Timer 2 - interrupt on match (ie. every 1 ms)
  TIMSK2 = bit (OCIE2A);   // enable Timer2 Interrupt

  TCNT1 = 0;      // Both counters to zero
  TCNT2 = 0;     

  // Reset prescalers
  GTCCR = bit (PSRASY);        // reset prescaler now
  // start Timer 2
  TCCR2B =  bit (CS20) | bit (CS22) ;  // prescaler of 128
  // start Timer 1
  // External clock source on T1 pin (D5). Clock on rising edge.
  TCCR1B =  bit (CS10) | bit (CS11) | bit (CS12);
  }  // end of startCounting

ISR (TIMER1_OVF_vect)
  {
  ++overflowCount;               // count number of Counter1 overflows  
  }  // end of TIMER1_OVF_vect


//******************************************************************
//  Timer2 Interrupt Service is invoked by hardware Timer 2 every 1 ms = 1000 Hz
//  16Mhz / 128 / 125 = 1000 Hz

ISR (TIMER2_COMPA_vect) 
  {
  // grab counter value before it changes any more
  unsigned int timer1CounterValue;
  timer1CounterValue = TCNT1;  // see datasheet, page 117 (accessing 16-bit registers)
  unsigned long overflowCopy = overflowCount;

  // see if we have reached timing period
  if (++timerTicks < timerPeriod) 
    return;  // not yet

  // if just missed an overflow
  if ((TIFR1 & bit (TOV1)) && timer1CounterValue < 256)
    overflowCopy++;

  // end of gate time, measurement ready

  TCCR1A = 0;    // stop timer 1
  TCCR1B = 0;    

  TCCR2A = 0;    // stop timer 2
  TCCR2B = 0;    

  TIMSK1 = 0;    // disable Timer1 Interrupt
  TIMSK2 = 0;    // disable Timer2 Interrupt

  // calculate total count
  timerCounts = (overflowCopy << 16) + timer1CounterValue;  // each overflow is 65536 more
  counterReady = true;              // set global flag for end count period
  }  // end of TIMER2_COMPA_vect

void setup () 
  {
  Serial.begin(115200);       
  Serial.println("Frequency Counter");
  } // end of setup

void loop () 
  {
  // stop Timer 0 interrupts from throwing the count out
  byte oldTCCR0A = TCCR0A;
  byte oldTCCR0B = TCCR0B;
  TCCR0A = 0;    // stop timer 0
  TCCR0B = 0;    

  startCounting (500);  // how many ms to count for

  while (!counterReady) 
     { }  // loop until count over

  // adjust counts by counting interval to give frequency in Hz
  float frq = (timerCounts *  1000.0) / timerPeriod;

  Serial.print ("Frequency: ");
  Serial.print ((unsigned long) frq);
  Serial.println (" Hz.");

  // restart timer 0
  TCCR0A = oldTCCR0A;
  TCCR0B = oldTCCR0B;

  // let serial stuff finish
  delay(200);
  }   // end of loop
```

Feeding in a 1 kHz sine wave (from 0V to 5V) I get this output:

```
Frequency Counter
Frequency: 1000 Hz.
Frequency: 1002 Hz.
Frequency: 1000 Hz.
Frequency: 1000 Hz.
Frequency: 1000 Hz.
Frequency: 1000 Hz.
Frequency: 1002 Hz.
Frequency: 1000 Hz.
Frequency: 1000 Hz.
Frequency: 1000 Hz.
```

There is the occasional mis-reading but it looks accurate enough. You might sample a few times, and if you get something between 990 and 1010, five times, you might consider that a match.

You will need to make sure that the input is in the range for triggering the input circuitry of the Arduino. It should be around 4 to 5V, and not higher than 5V (for a high). It also should not go negative.

Something like this will protect the input pin:

[image: Input protection]

**Warning** - audio from an audio jack will be AC and it **will** go negative. Make sure you use a suitable input protection.

---

### Amplification

After looking at [Wikipedia - Line level](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Line_level) it seems likely that the output from your phone will not be high enough (around 700 mV probably). Therefore a simple transistor amplifier will probably be required to raise it to a level that can be detected.

Inspired by [this post](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/36795/using-a-microphone-with-an-arduino) on Electronics Stack Exchange, I made up a simple amplifier:

[image: Audio amplifier schematic]

Testing out with around 500mV peak-to-peak input indicates that it successfully amplified it to 0 to 5V DC:

[image: Audio amplifier scope trace]

---

### Alternative method with analog comparator

Based on suggestions by Chris Stratton, there is another way of doing this.

You can use the [analog comparator](http://www.gammon.com.au/forum/?id=11916) to detect an analog signal passing a threshold, like this:

[image: Analog comparator schematic]

I have set up the voltage divider to trigger at 0.265V, so that a 500 mV signal should provide an acceptable triggering range.

As for the sketch, at these frequencies we can do something simpler than what I posted before:

```C++
volatile bool counting;
volatile unsigned long count;

ISR (ANALOG_COMP_vect)
  {
  if (counting)
    count++;
  }

void setup ()
  {
  Serial.begin (115200);
  Serial.println ("Started.");
  ADCSRB = 0;           // (Disable) ACME: Analog Comparator Multiplexer Enable
  ACSR =  bit (ACI)     // (Clear) Analog Comparator Interrupt Flag
        | bit (ACIE)    // Analog Comparator Interrupt Enable
        | bit (ACIS1);  // ACIS1, ACIS0: Analog Comparator Interrupt Mode Select (trigger on falling edge)
   }  // end of setup

unsigned long startTime;

void loop ()
  {

  if (!counting)
    {
    startTime = micros ();
    count = 0;
    counting = true;
    }
  else
    {
    // is a second up? (1000000 microseconds)
    if (micros () - startTime >= 1000000)
      {
      counting = false;
      Serial.print (count);
      Serial.println (F(" Hz."));
      }  // end of a second being up

    }  // end of if

  }  // end of loop
```

Comment: You don't need an amplifier, if you are going to do single-tresholding detection anyway, the ATmega has an analog comparator usable by the timer.  What you did miss is the DC blocking capacitor in your first circuit.  Choose one that makes the impedance high (especially in combination with any resistor) enough to use the internal protection diodes, rather than trying to find an external one that creates the right limitation.

Comment: @ChrisStratton :  Yes, good idea. I've edited with an alternative method along the lines of what you suggested.

Comment: I'm afraid you still don't quite have it. The diode remains a distraction and you need to bias to your threshold, which would ordinarily be placed somewhere more like half the operating voltage.

Comment: Well, @ChrisStratton, I would be pleased if you would post an answer explaining your solution in detail. Just saying that I have it wrong isn't helping me or anyone else, like the OP.

Comment: `you need to bias to your threshold` - I was assuming that the incoming signal was around 700mV ([Line Level](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Line_level)) - and indeed that worked in my test. Feel free to post other figures.

Comment: Nice description and quick prototyping!  I totally missed that the signal did not have any other background noise, it's just the 1kHz tone.

Comment: How to do this on a Attiny85? Code does not compile. I want to use an old phone with touchscreen that uses a (local) webpage as button interface and connected via audio to the Attiny85. Each button produces a sound (wave) at different Hz to be unique and to identify which button is pressed. Came along this article because there are not much articles about using (an old phone's) audio as interface to interact with a hardware project. It doesn't sound impossible, like your example describes. Possible to do this on Attiny? Will be great.

Answer (score 5):

If your signal is a pure 1 kHz tone, then you should use Nick
Gammon's counting method, as it is the most straight-forward solution.
If, however, you are picking the signal through a microphone, chances
are you will also get some background noise, and this can make the
counting method unreliable.

In such a case, you will have to use some kind of digital filter to
extract the desired signal from the noise. I would recommend using
[homodyne detection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Homodyne_detection),
which is both simple and very robust against wide-spectrum noise: let
*f* = 1 kHz be the frequency you want to detect, and *t*
be the current time, then

- compute cos(2 π *f t* ) and sin(2 π *f t* ): these two periodic signals,
  in quadrature to one another, are called “the local oscillator”
- multiply your signal independently by the above cos() and sin()
- low-pass filter the two products, which gives you the
  [I and Q demodulated](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadrature_amplitude_modulation) signals
- compute the instantaneous power = I<sup>2</sup> + Q<sup>2</sup>.

You know the phone is ringing when this power goes above some
experimentally-determined threshold.

I know all this sounds like heavy math, but it need not be:

- All the computations are amenable to efficient fixed-point
  implementations, and you can do the math in parallel with the
  analog-to-digital conversion.
- The scheme works even with crude approximations of the sin() and cos()
  functions. Even square waves (sin() and cos() being always +1 or −1)
  work quite decently.
- The low-pass filter can be implemented as an
  [exponential moving
  average](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moving_average#Exponential_moving_average),
  which is only a bit shift, an add and a subtract.

I can try to write some sample code, but I would go through the trouble
only if there is interest. If your signal is so clean that Nick Gammon's
method works reliably, there probably is no point.

---

**EDIT**: I wrote a program to demonstrate this approach, just for the
fun. It's available as a GitHub gist:
[homodyne.ino](https://gist.github.com/edgar-bonet/0b03735d70366bc05fc6).
I am not copying the whole program here, just adding some explanations:

The first thing is to take care of the sampling frequency. Whenever one
wants to do signal processing, it is very desirable to sample at a fixed
and known frequency. This is next to impossible to achieve by looping
over `analogRead()`, because the CPU time needed to go through the loop
is hard to predict, as it can be influenced by interrupts and by
conditional branches. `analogRead()` is also highly inefficient, as it
locks the CPU in a busy loop while it waits for the analog-to-digital
converter (ADC) to do its job.

The solution is to put the ADC in the so called "free running mode". In
this mode, it starts a conversion as soon as the previous one is
finished, which gives a very steady sampling rate of 9.615 kHz (one
sample every 104 µs). The samples are handled by an interrupt
service routine called `ISR(ADC_vect)` which gets triggered every time a
sample is ready. This is also where all the signal processing is done.

Below is a detailed explanation of every line of code in the ISR:

```c++
int8_t sample = ADCH - 128;
```

Reading the ADC result is the first thing to do in the ISR. Since we do
not need the full 10 bit resolution, the ADC was configured to
left-adjust its result. Then we get an 8-bit result by just reading the
high byte of the ADC data register. We subtract 128 to remove the DC
offset and get a signed number in the range [−128 .. +127].

Next, we update the phase of our local oscillator:

```c++
static uint16_t phase;
phase += PHASE_INC;
```

We need not worry about possible overflows: since the phase is kept in
units of 1/2<sup>16</sup> cycles, the increment automatically works
modulo one cycle. The phase increment should theoretically be 6815.744,
which is rounded to 6816. This makes the local oscillator fast by
0.0376 Hz, which is negligible given the accuracy of the Arduino
clock. The phase could be kept in an 8-bit variable, but the rounding
error would then make the oscillator fast by 14 Hz, which can be
borderline unacceptable.

Next we need to build two square waves in quadrature, which will be used
as rough approximations of sin() and cos(). But since the most
significant bit of the phase is on during half of the cycle, it can be
used as one of our square waves. The other wave is obtained in a similar
way, after adding 1/4 cycle to the phase. So here is how we multiply our
sample by the square waves:

```c++
int8_t x = sample;
if (((phase>>8) + 0x00) & 0x80) x = -1 - x;
int8_t y = sample;
if (((phase>>8) + 0x40) & 0x80) y = -1 - y;
```

The expression `phase>>8` is only meant to hint the compiler that it
needs only to consider the most significant byte of the phase. This
should normally not be needed, but I noticed that, without this hint,
gcc generates suboptimal code. The `-1` in the above lines are for
avoiding a possible overflow.

Next comes the low-pass filter:

```c++
signal_I += x - (signal_I >> LOG_TAU);
signal_Q += y - (signal_Q >> LOG_TAU);
```

Where `signal_I` and `signal_Q` are `volatile int16_t` globals, and
`LOG_TAU` is 6. This filters with a time constant

> τ = 64 × 104 µs = 6.656 ms

which translates to a −3 dB bandwidth of

> Δf = 1/(2πτ) = 23.9 Hz.

which is fairly narrow for a 1 kHz signal. The significance of τ is
that, once the tone starts, it takes the filter about
2.3 τ ≈ 15 ms to reach 90% of its final output. Both
τ and Δf can be changed by simply changing `LOG_TAU`.

This ISR takes about 176 CPU cycles (11 µs, including the
4 cycles needed to put the CPU in interrupt mode) every
1664 cycles (104 µs). This amounts to about 10.6% of the
available CPU power. And since everything is done inside the ISR, the
program is free to do whatever else needs to be done while the data
acquisition and digital filtering happens in the background.

I tested the program by sending it a sine wave of 4.36 V
peak-to-peak amplitude. The reported power fluctuated quite a bit, but
here are the approximate average readings as a function of the input
frequency:

```
frequency  |  power
-----------+-------
   929 Hz  |   480
   976 Hz  |  2400
  1005 Hz  |  4600
  1028 Hz  |  2700
  1079 Hz  |   480
```